# Set Active Sheet in Laravel-Excel 3.0

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I've used previous versions of [Laravel-Excel](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/3.0/) to export data and in the past I've been able to use `$sheets->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->download('xls');` ([link to PHPSpreadsheet documentation](https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/master/PhpOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/Spreadsheet.html#method_setActiveSheetIndex)) to set the active tab when the user opens the file.

In version 3.0, I can't figure out where to put this. The file downloads if I don't try to set the active sheet so the rest of the code is valid. I've tried adding it inside the export controller as shown below and it throws an error `Call to undefined method App\Exports\TechMatrixExport::setActiveSheetIndex()`. In the example below I want TechnologiesSheet to be the active when when the user opens the file.

```
namespace App\Exports;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMultipleSheets;


class TechMatrixExport implements WithMultipleSheets
{
    use Exportable;

    public function sheets(): array
    {

        $sheets = [];        
        $sheets[] = new TechnologiesSheet();
        $sheets[] = new NotesSheet();
        $sheets[] = new InputsSheet();
        $sheets[] = new ReferencesSheet();

        return $sheets;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function __construct(\Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel $excel)
{
    $this->excel = $excel;
}

public function exportAll() 
{
    return (new TechMatrixExport)->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->download('tech_matrix.xlsx');
}
```

Where does the `->setActiveSheetIndex(0);` belong?

Comment: The code certainly looks correct according to the docs, so you're not crazy. 

Can you do a dd(TechMatrixExport) just to confirm you're actually getting an instance of  `Spreadsheet`? That's where the function lives:

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/master/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Spreadsheet.php#L809

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use BeforeWriting (https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/3.0/exports/extending.html#available-events) to setActiveSheetIndex.

I added RegistersEventListeners to your code, I got it working this way in my project, let me know if this works for you.

```
namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMultipleSheets;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithEvents;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\RegistersEventListeners;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\BeforeExport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Events\BeforeWriting;

class TechMatrixExport implements WithMultipleSheets, WithEvents
{
  use Exportable, RegistersEventListeners;

  public function registerEvents(): array
  {
    return [
      // Handle by a closure.
      BeforeExport::class => function(BeforeExport $event) {
          $event->writer->getProperties()->setCreator('You')->setTitle("Title");
      },
      BeforeWriting::class => function(BeforeWriting $event) {
          $event->writer->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
      },
    ];
  }

  public function sheets(): array
  {
    $sheets = [];        
    $sheets[] = new TechnologiesSheet();
    $sheets[] = new NotesSheet();
    $sheets[] = new InputsSheet();
    $sheets[] = new ReferencesSheet();

    return $sheets;
  }
}
```